# How to query relational data in laravel using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `Project` Model each Project has Many Positions from `Position` Model and each positions has Many Employees in `Employee` Model

Now I want to query all employees id's of the particular project regardless their position,

How can I achieve this using eloquent?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: I think your question is well described, but at stackoverflow you will need to have the code you tried to solve it with included and or some steps to reproduce your problem, your question is very abstract and for future reference you will need to include more :)

Comment: That was helpful @nakov

Answer (score 1):

Roughly you would do something similar to this, where you can use whereHas to create nested queries on relations.

```
$employeeIdsToFilter = [1,2,3];

$filteredProjects = Project::query()->
    whereHas('positions' , function ($query) use ($employeeIdsToFilter) {
        $query->whereHas('employees', function($query) use ($employeeIdsToFilter) {
            $query->whereIn('id', $employeeIdsToFilter);
        });
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HasManyThough` relation. Here is the [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)